# pandas: checking for nulls: what did I do wrong applying this function by row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to check if some records in some (not all) of the columns in a dataframe are null; to do this, I want to create T/F fields, which I will then need to group by. E.g. if I have a field 'x' then I want to create a 'x POPULATED' field, and so on.

In my context, null means NaN, the string 'not available', or the string 'nan'.

I have tried the code below, but it doesn't work - I get:

```
ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index 0')
```

**My questions are**:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Is there a better way to vectorise this? Even if there is, and I'm pretty sure there is, I'd still like to understand what I was doing wrong in my code.

Code:

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['a']=np.arange(0,10)
df['b']='test'
df['c']='nothing to test here'
df.iloc[0,:]=np.nan
df.iloc[1,1]='not available'
df.iloc[2,1]='nan'

def checknull(x):
    if pd.isnull(x) or x=='not available' or x=='nan':
        return False
    else:
        return True
    
for c in ['a','b']:
    df[c + 'populated'] =  df.apply( lambda x: checknull(df[c]) , axis=1 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For vectorized solution need [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html) with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) for mask and then invert by `~`:

```
df1 = ~(df[['a','b']].isnull() | (df[['a','b']].isin(['not available','nan'])))

print (df1)
       a      b
0  False  False
1   True  False
2   True  False
3   True   True
4   True   True
5   True   True
6   True   True
7   True   True
8   True   True
9   True   True
```

Last add new columns to original by [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with [`add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html):

```
df = df.join(df1.add_suffix('populated'))
print (df)
     a              b                     c  apopulated  bpopulated
0  NaN            NaN                   NaN       False       False
1  1.0  not available  nothing to test here        True       False
2  2.0            nan  nothing to test here        True       False
3  3.0           test  nothing to test here        True        True
4  4.0           test  nothing to test here        True        True
5  5.0           test  nothing to test here        True        True
6  6.0           test  nothing to test here        True        True
7  7.0           test  nothing to test here        True        True
8  8.0           test  nothing to test here        True        True
9  9.0           test  nothing to test here        True        True
```

In your original code need `x[c]` instead `df[c]`, because check each row separately:

```
for c in ['a','b']:
    df[c + 'populated'] =  df.apply( lambda x: checknull(x[c]) , axis=1 )

print (df)
     a              b                     c  apopulated  bpopulated
0  NaN            NaN                   NaN       False       False
1  1.0  not available  nothing to test here        True       False
2  2.0            nan  nothing to test here        True       False
3  3.0           test  nothing to test here        True        True
4  4.0           test  nothing to test here        True        True
5  5.0           test  nothing to test here        True        True
6  6.0           test  nothing to test here        True        True
7  7.0           test  nothing to test here        True        True
8  8.0           test  nothing to test here        True        True
9  9.0           test  nothing to test here        True        True
```

Comment: Thanks! What a stupid mistake! :( Is your example vectorised while mine isn't? Or is isin() not vectorised?